# What are the places one should look for CSRF flaw?

Tags: web-application, csrf

While finding vulnerabilities in a web app what are the potential areas where one should look for CSRF flaw?

Answer (score 2):

Cross site request forgery (CSRF) is performing a "forged" request from the attacker's site to another site where the victim is logged in. If that site is vulnerable, any action that the user could normally perform on the site can now be performed by the attacker.

An interesting action to perform through CSRF is changing the password or email address, as this results in account takeover. For passwords this is often impossible since you have to fill in the old password, but for email addresses this is sometimes forgotten.

Other interesting actions depend very much on what the purpose is of the attacked site. Here on sec.se, I would trigger upvotes on all my questions and answers through CSRF.

Requests that perform some action are supposed to have CSRF protection and are interesting to test. Most of the time these are POST requests, but not always. Some sites do have CSRF protection on all POST requests, but not on GET requests. In that case it is interesting to search for a GET request that performs some action.

One request that can often be forged is to log out the user. On most sites, simply visiting /logout or something like that will log out the user. This is technically CSRF, although with a rather mundane impact.

CSRF protection is typically done by sending a random token along with any request. The attacker wouldn't have this token and thus can't forge a valid request.

Sometimes the site verifies the Referer or Origin headers to verify that the request came from the site itself. This can be secure, but is a bit harder to get correct. Sometimes the site checks whether "https://www.example.com/" is *contained* in the Referer, in which case it can be attacked by using "https://www.attacker.com/?https://www.example.com/" as the attacking page. Sometimes the check isn't done if the Referer header is missing, which the attacker can trigger through a [referrer policy](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/06/21/bypass-csrf-check-using-referrer-policy/).

Finally, [Same-Site cookies](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/) provide adequate protection against CSRF, but only for browsers that support them.

Comment: You explained about CSRF which I already know. The question is what are the places where chances are CSRF flaw may occur.

Comment: @Ashwin Literally any request that changes application state.

Answer (score 2):

The short version is, as @AndrolGenhald put it, "Literally any request that changes application state." The most *common* places to look are HTML `<form>` tags, since the entire point of those is to provide a way to send data to the server (generally changing the web app's state), but you can also find non-idempotent (state-changing) requests in other places, such as XHR or Fetch requests, or GET requests initiated by links or non-"submit" buttons.

Generally, a good way to find CSRF is to walk a website yourself, while proxying all the traffic through an HTTP intercepting proxy (Burp Suite is the standard tool for pentesters, but in a pinch you can use other proxies as well). The proxy will show you what the actual network traffic is, including stuff you might not even know was there. Any time you do something that changes the state of the application, check the network traffic in the proxy log and see if there's any kind of CSRF protection token. You can also validate that the token is used correctly by doing things like re-playing requests without the correct token or without the token at all, or comparing two different user sessions to ensure that the token is different and one user cannot predict another user's token.

In most cases, unless the server has done something very foolish with its CORS configuration, request types other than GET, HEAD, POST, or OPTIONS cannot be made cross-site, so verbs like PUT, PATCH, etc. are probably fine. Bear in mind, however, that some servers will let you use the "wrong" verb for a request and honor it anyhow; try changing the request method and seeing if it still goes through. Similarly, content types other than URL-encoded forms and plain text are hard to send cross-origin, but sometimes a server that expects JSON will happily accept a request that contains valid JSON in the body but claims the content-type is `text/plain`, and a CSRF attacker *can* send that.